# How to connect flutter app with socket.io used with node.js?

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I just need a plugin or a snippet code for connecting flutter app with socket.io used with node js

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socket_io 
example code https://github.com/WinkMeter/flutter_socket_io/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart 
or
package https://pub.dev/packages/adhara_socket_io 
example code https://github.com/infitio/flutter_socket_io/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart